# Python regex to remove all leading numbers including underscores

Tags: python, regex

How can i modify my existing regex to make it remove all the leading characters that are either a digit or an underscore.

```
re.sub('^(\d+|_).*', '', n, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# test strings
0001_Smoke_B_B
0002_Smoke_B_B
0012_Smoke_B_B
MA103
MA104
00_00MA105
```

The end goal should output these

```
Smoke_B_B
Smoke_B_B
Smoke_B_B
MA103
MA104
MA105
```

Comment: maybe you should use `*` without `.` ?

Comment: you could format data into code which we could simple copy and run. You could create list with examples and `for`-loop which test every string with regex

Comment: Use a character class instead of an alternation, it's more efficient: `re.sub('^[\d_]+', '', n, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: There's no need for a regex here. `str.lstrip` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Regex for replace

`^[\d_]+`

`^` This looks for beginning of string

`[\d_]` Character array with A digit or underscore

`+` 1 or more times

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5vDH4A/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `.` then it will use `*` to search all digits and `_`

```
'^(\d+|_)*'
```

---

Testing code.

I also added `'^[\d+_]+'` from other answers/comments

```
import re

# test strings
examples = [
    '0001_Smoke_B_B',
    '0002_Smoke_B_B',
    '0012_Smoke_B_B',
    'MA103',
    'MA104',
    '00_00MA105'
]

for text in examples:
    result = re.sub('^(\d+|_)*', '', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    print(text, '->', result)

# example from other answers and comments
for text in examples:
    result = re.sub('^[\d+_]+', '', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    print(text, '->', result)
```